# How can I run a Greasemonkey script when page changed via ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have that script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     example
// @include  http://xxx*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var findElem = function(elems, text) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (elems[i].textContent == text) {
            return elems[i];
        } else {
            var result = findElem(elems[i].children, text);
            if (result != undefined) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}

switch (document.getElementById('my_id').value) {
    case "1":
        findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla1").click();
        break;
    case "2":
        findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla2").click();
        break;
    case "3":
        findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla3").click();
        break;
    case "4":
        findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla4").click();
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

It works fine but it works only main page load. I want to run this when page changed via ajax. How can I do that?

Also please give examples with your answers. I'm newbie. I don't know how to use things in your answers.

Comment: List exactly what is changing. Show enough of the HTML structure that we can pick accurate selectors -- link to the target page of it's not supremely difficult.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since browser's environment is event-driven you'll have to either set up a timer, bind to some event that happens around update you looking for. Alternatively, you can wrap function that does update and call your code in post-hook. Obviously, you'll need to wrap your userscript code in some function to reuse.

Here's an example with timer set up with [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) (top of script is still the same):

```
setInterval(function(){
    switch (document.getElementById('my_id').value) {
        case "1":
            findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla1").click();
            break;
        case "2":
            findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla2").click();
            break;
        case "3":
            findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla3").click();
            break;
        case "4":
            findElem(document.documentElement.children, "blabla4").click();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}, 1000) // if AJAX updates happen with some specific interval, set same number here to minimize useless work
```

Comment: Timer listening is actually a pretty nice solution, if ajax reloading of the page's content is also triggered by setTimeout/setInterval.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know can I do that. Can you give example or edit my code to do that?

Comment: Well, you really should read basic documentation on events and timers then. As you can see from example change is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If your host is using jQuery, then you can use [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) or [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/):

```
function mainCode(){
    // your script logic here ...
    switch (document.getElementById('my_id').value) {
        // truncated to save space
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    mainCode();
    unsafeWindow.$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, opt) {
        mainCode();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [mutation event handler](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) to trigger your function each time the html is altered. However, browsersupport is not the best;)

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to use it. Can you give example or edit my code to do that?

Comment: Did you catch the part about [mutation events are deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents) and they are not recommended by Mozilla, even Firefox supports them for now (but not in the future).

Comment: @BrockAdams I know, but it's a possible way and there are [Mutation Observers](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#mutation-observers) on the way anyways.